# How I connect Visual Studio App center from TFS (On premise)

Tags: xamarin, tfs, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

We are planning to use Visual Studio App center to build, Test the mobile application and currently we have all the code in TFS (TFVC), Is it possible to configure a link from TFS to Visual Studio App Center ?

Answer (score 4):

Not with TFVC. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/):

> App Center supports building apps in Git repositories hosted on:
>
> - Bitbucket
> - GitHub
> - Azure DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services or> VSTS)
>
> **App Center does not support Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC)**

Emphasis mine.